Laravel Blade templates not compiled correctly in production environment even though they are compiled correctly in development environment
I have a Laravel project (recently upgraded to version 11) that works perfectly in my development environment.  It was also working perfectly in my production environment until yesterday, when all the pages started to generate errors.  The git repos in the two environments are in sync, and the current code in the repo is checked out on the production server.  The error that is being generated on every page is Undefined variable $component.  The start of the PHP file generated from the blade file for the login page, quoted in the "View Exception" that is reported, for example, is
@component('App\View\Components\GuestLayout', 'guest-layout', [])
<?php if (isset($attributes) && $attributes instanceof Illuminate\View\ComponentAttributeBag): ?>
<?php $attributes = $attributes->except(\App\View\Components\GuestLayout::ignoredParameterNames()); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $component->withAttributes([]); ?>

Indeed, $component is not defined, so I understand why PHP is complaining.  But what I don't understand is why Laravel is generating a PHP file that has this error on my production server (but not on my development server, even though the codebases are the same).
What code on the production server could generate this error?
I tried clearing the cache (php artisan cache:clear, php artisan view:clear), but that made no difference.
Any suggestions on how I should proceed?

It turned out that restarting Apache on the production server solved the problem.  I have no idea why.

I had the same error, but in my case it was caused by an incomplete upgrade from Laravel 10 to 11. I created a new Laravel 11 project and updated my files and now it works.
Today on a new Laravel project I had a similar error and also Blade not processing directives. It was solved running php artisan optimize:clear
